# cfgmgr like command under Linux?

Tags: linux, devices, hot-plug

`cfgmgr` is a command under AIX/ksh that checks for new hardware; e.g. new HDD's that have been added without a shutdown.

Question: Are there any similar commands under Linux? If "fdisk -l" doesn't recognize the new HDD (only after reboot). Or is Linux different from AIX, and this command is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, with modern hardware, a modern kernel, and a modern distribution, hardware recognition should happen automatically.

There is, however, a program called "[kudzu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kudzu_%28computer_daemon%29)" which will do what you want — attempt to detect new hardware, and add the appropriate configuration. I think, because of the changes in modern systems, it's not really maintained anymore (and for several years, I think it has been more trouble than it's worth). But if you are on an older system, or building something yourself and for whatever reason don't want to do it the modern way, you might find that useful.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your hardware allows for hotplugging hard drives, I'm fairly sure any modern linux distro should instantly spot the added drive and create device numbers to access it, generally via `udev`.

Comment: are you sure there is not "cfgmgr" like command under linux?

Comment: i think yast can do this, no?

Answer (score 1):

For hard disk partitions (e.g. after modifying partition tables), have a look at the [`partprobe` command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/re-read-the-partition-table-without-rebooting-linux-system.html).

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu-Debian you can use Partprobe (http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/re-read-the-partition-table-without-rebooting-linux-system.html) but if you want to detected all LUN's (also RAID Software) I prefer `scsitools` package (command: `sudo rescan-scsi-bus`).